# Random Message Disocrd.js V14

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, discord.js

```
if(message === "8ball"){
      
           
            rndmessage(message);
            function rndmessage(message){
               var messages =['**NO**','**YES**','**MAYBE**','**NEVER**','**ASK AGAIN**','**YES DEFINITELY.**','**DONT COUNT ON IT**','**BETTER NOT TELL YOU NOW**','**MY REPLY IS NO**','**YOU MAY RELY ON IT**','** AS I SEE IT, YES**'];
               var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*message.length);
         
               message.reply(message[rnd]);
            
            
            
            }
                               }
```

how to do after 8ball if user says anything its reply to him

Comment: Send `messages[rnd]` not `message[rnd]` since `messages` is your array

Comment: And use `messages.length`, as you want to pick an item from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Nice code! It should work if you do:

```
if(message === "8ball"){
    rndmessage(message);
    function rndmessage(message){
        var messages =['**NO**','**YES**','**MAYBE**','**NEVER**','**ASK AGAIN**','**YES DEFINITELY.**','**DONT COUNT ON IT**','**BETTER NOT TELL YOU NOW**','**MY REPLY IS NO**','**YOU MAY RELY ON IT**','** AS I SEE IT, YES**'];
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*messages.length);
         
        message.reply({ content: rnd })     
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!